# What is the best extension for Image changing on Joomla CMS?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I have this specific requirement that there is a list of names of people and a container for photo.
So when I click on specific user's name, his photo will appear in that container.

Is there any specific extension for this, so that admin can manage all the people names with their images ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is actually just a list of Team Members. E.g. if there is website for a corporate company, there is a page for Team members. This is something like that. So the extension I am looking for should have only those features. It has nothing to do with authors.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to an Avatar and using Joomla 2.5+ then I would recommend using [Community Builder](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/communities/210). I know it's a fairly big system, however it extends user profiles massively and might come in handy in the future.

If you're using Joomla 1.5 then you could always use [DAvatar](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-presence/profiles/8028) which is simply a plugin.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can user Community Builder as well but its very large & powerful extension & i think your interested to show only users image. If you have Joomla 2.5 then Profile Picture plugin will be most suitable for your case. Here is the link check it out. http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/user-management/19702 . Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Community builder is overkill just to get an image.
Here are a few options, depending on how often these are updated and whether you want to allow users to update these themselves.

Of course you can always make a category and an article for each team member, then use the links and urls to load the image in a standard location (override +use css in your template to do this). Use ACL to manage who can change this and to decide if you will allow users to manage.

Use the image field in the contact component, put all of the team members in the same category in contact. Put bio etc in miscellanous information. Only admins can manage this since it is edited back end only.

Use a profile plugin for com_user if you want users to be able to manage for themselves.